# Trying 20.04 LTS - Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server

Tags: 20.04, gdm, amd-ryzen

I've just installed new relase LTS from USD Stick into my own new DeskTop new PC Gammer
AMD Ryzen 5 - Asus  PRIME A320M - MSI GeeForce GTX 1650 Super Gammer . MAxtor SSD 240Gb - WDC 2Tb SATA
I booted Ubuntu from USB worked fine, install process finished success, Ubuntu booted ok, but cannot start GDM as asking me for password.

Here is a fatal error on syslog:

```
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 systemd[10067]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 evolution-addre[20857]: Error setting property 'ConnectionStatus' on interface org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Source: La conexión está cerrada (g-io-error-quark, 18)
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 systemd[10067]: dbus.service: Succeeded.
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 systemd[10067]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 systemd[10067]: evolution-source-registry.service: Succeeded.
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 systemd[10067]: gvfs-afc-volume-monitor.service: Succeeded.
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 systemd[10067]: evolution-calendar-factory.service: Succeeded.
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 systemd[10067]: gvfs-daemon.service: Succeeded.
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 systemd[10067]: Started D-Bus User Message Bus.
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 dbus-daemon[20974]: [session uid=1000 pid=20974] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 systemd[10067]: gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service: Succeeded.
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 systemd[10067]: evolution-addressbook-factory.service: Succeeded.
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 gnome-shell[20980]: The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 gnome-shell[20980]: > Warning:          Unsupported maximum keycode 569, clipping.
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 gnome-shell[20980]: >                   X11 cannot support keycodes above 255.
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 gnome-shell[20980]: > Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym Invalid
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 gnome-shell[20980]: Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 systemd[10067]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 systemd[10067]: gsd-media-keys.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 systemd[10067]: gsd-keyboard.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 systemd[10067]: gsd-power.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 systemd[10067]: gsd-color.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
May 14 20:29:29 AMD-PcGammer-Ryzen-5 systemd[10067]: gsd-wacom.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
```

Comment: I choosed install 3rd party software when installed, so I'm not sure if there is a video hardware compat issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this trouble by reinstalling, but did not select download 3rd party drivers, and remove last installation.